# Simulate input resistance

Tags: transistors, simulation, multisim

I am quite new to electronic engineering. I have a circuit and I have calculated the input resistance to be about 0.65 kOhm. To verify the calculation I would like to simulate the circuit. Is there a good sophisticated method to simulate the input resistance.

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about varying the series resistance or calculating the input resistance?

Comment: Looks like you can print **Uin** AC voltage (831.10mV). Can you also print AC current through **Vin**?

Comment: @VoltageSpike I am talking about simulating the input resistance, to verify if calculations are correct.

Comment: @glen_geek Yes I can switch to AC current.

Comment: Add same to source and is matched at Vin/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't recognize your simulator. In LTSpice, and other SPICEs you can plot input impedance. LTSpice recognizes Volts/amps as an impedance, and plots ohms. So plotting the voltage source divided by the current flowing through that source will plot an impedance....
[image: Circuit LTSpice]

Given a circuit like this (above), LTSpice can directly plot input impedance as a function of frequency. Note that the phase plot (as a dotted line) is directional. Looks like phase is upside down, so a 180 degree phase shift is in order....LTSpice current directions are sometimes opposite to the directions you or I might imagine.[image: AC analysis LTSpice plots impedance]

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use the voltage source and put a resistor in series with it. Then use a parameter sweep on the resistor to vary it's resistance.

The method for doing this is described in detail here:http://www.ni.com/tutorial/12777/en/

In short you can do this from the analyze parameters screen, select the resistor and input different values that it should change to. Multisim will then run multiple simulations and only change the resistor value. You can also run print statements to find things like the output voltage.

[image]